# Function the_content

Tags: functions, templates, hooks, the-content, images

For some reason on my attachment page template (http://capa.furniture/?attachment_id=1494) I am getting the url of the reduced size image. I do not know why. I am not getting the thumbnail full size but a smaller size as you can see here -> http://cl.ly/image/3E1x1q3m070u

How can I make it so that the attachment page shows the full image link in the html so the quality is better?

Answer (score 0):

What's the code that shows the image? Maybe try:

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $post->ID, 'full' ); ?>
```

This works on the attachment page in my gallery theme.

Comment: The theme I'm using uses this '<?php the_content(); ?>'. I cannot find what is creating the output.

Comment: In what file did you see `the_content()`?

Comment: the_content creates the output - that's the function that displays post content